# Restoring Database PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, odoo-8, database-backups

One of my servers has a virus and the Postgres service in Windows is not running a backup and I'm using Odoo8 and even the Odoo Service is not running.

Is it possible to restore a database using only a OID directory which from what I know is the database file of Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean  `/data/base/<oid>` directory. Unfortunately it's not enough. There are some settings stored outside database `oid` directory as you called it.

**Ex:**

- `/data/glboal/` - cluster users' settings (passwords, roles etc)
- `/data/pg_xlog/` - WAL entries - possibly with transactions changes not "transfered" to database files yet.
- `/data/pg_tblspc/` - tablespaces

You need whole `/data` directory. Read more about `PHYSICAL BACKUP`.

### Edit:

So, if whole `/data` is available for you, you can restore database to other server. There's one thing you should remember: destination postrges cluster must be at the same varsion ex. `9.4.1`. When the first and seccond numbers match (ex `9.2.10` and `9.2.16`) this should also work most of the times. Keeping that in mind, you just need to replace `/data/` directory on destination server with your source `/data` directory (destination server must be stopped during that operation).

Comment: Its Only ok for me if its the whole data directory that will be copied! is it Possible to restore it?

Comment: sir thanks for your answer to my question, I've tried what you've said and right now its working!!
Before I've copy the data directory I've stop the Postgre Service in Win and the Odoo Service and copy the file and Start again the said Services